# how to prove that if Y(t) is a regular curve then it's arc length s starting at any point of Y(t) is a smooth function of t?

Tags: differential-geometry

[click here to see the proof of the theorem which i found in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvAsB.png)

in the proof they said that to simplify the notation, assume from now on that Y is a plane curve, say Y(t)=(u(t),v(t)),    where u and v are smooth function of t.
but in the proposition we have given that Y is regular so how we can say that for all regular curve Y , u and v will be smooth, because the proposition is true for all regular curve.

Comment: Define regular curve.

Comment: a point Y(t) of a parametrised curve Y is called regular point if derivative of Y at point t is not zero, and if derivative of Y is not zero for all point in the domain of Y  then Y is called a regular curve

Comment: You assume $Y$ is $C^\infty?$

Comment: in that case proposition becomes trivial , but the proposition is true for all kind of parametrised curves.

Comment: What are the definitions of "smooth" and "regular".

Comment: a function whose all derivative exists is called smooth and the function whose first order derivative exists and first order derivative is not zero at any point then it is regular.

Comment: The result is clearly not true for all regular curves, if regular allows curves that are only $C^1.$

Comment: but since the proposition is used in whole differential geometry and if we are using always C∞ then there was no need to define regular and smooth curve individually and even more every regular curve will be smooth in that case, which does not make any sense .

Comment: If all curves are smooth, then "regular" is the subset of smooth curves whose derivative vectors never vanish. Still a useful definition.